# Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая перед «да»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*Но, впрочем, нам тогда глазеть на него **да** и вообще возиться с ним было некогда.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении оборот с присоединительным союзом ДА И **обособляется:**

*Но, впрочем, нам тогда глазеть на него,  **да и вообще возиться с ним**,  было некогда.*

Пояснение

1. Союз ДА И является **присоединительным** и используется для обозначения **дополнительных сообщений**.  В середине предложения обороты с этим союзом **обособляются,** например:

В её взгляде, ДА И во всём поведении, появилось что-то новое.

Он не создал, ДА И  не мог создать, ни одного крупного произведения.

В этом взгляде, да и во всём поведении Лидии, явилось нечто новое.

В этом предложении, да и в двух соседних, сказуемое выражено краткой формой прилагательного

2. Примечание

Но в некоторых случаях союз ДА И используется **как соединительный** (эти варианты указаны у Розенталя)

(1) Обороты с присоединительным союзом ДА И без обособления

Если присоединительная конструкция **тесно связана по смыслу** с последующей частью высказывания и перед ней не предусмотрена пауза, то она может только ОТДЕЛЯТЬСЯ запятой от предшествующей части предложения:

***Поздно теперь, да и не к чему** возвращаться к этому вопросу. При проведении подобных сложных экспериментов **трудно, да и невозможно** избежать отдельных ошибок.*

(2) **Частица ДА** и соединительный союз И (нет запятой)

Частицу ДА в этом случае можно ИЗЪЯТЬ из предложения: Я слушаю, слушаю  да и  засну. Вот пошёл он в лес по орехи да и заблудился.
Поехал в город да и не вернулсЯ.

Comment: Объясните еще раз на пальцах разницу между предложения в вашем ответе, в которых оборот с ‟да и” обособляется и теми оборотами, которые имеют только запятую слева. Какая разница между: ‟В её взгляде, ДА И во всём поведении, появилось что-то новое”(обособление) и ‟Поздно теперь, да и не к чему возвращаться к этому вопросу”(только слева); какая разница между: ‟Он не создал, ДА И не мог создать, ни одного крупного произведения”(обособление) и ‟При проведении подобных сложных экспериментов трудно, да и невозможно избежать отдельных ошибок”(только слева). Объясните на пальцах. Вот я в упор не вижу.

Comment: Помогите понять кодифицированный замысел в этом вопросе этой замечательной науки.

Comment: Да, и где вы взяли примеры с обособлением, потому что у Розенталя я вижу только одно из трех. Причём одно предложение является вами переделанным другим предложением.

Comment: И по поводу частицы ‟да”. Можно хоть один учебник или статью, где ‟да и” классифицируется частицей ‟да” союзом ‟и”?

Comment: Jim Korbett, вы предлагаете мне провести семинар, подробно ответив на большое количество ваших вопросов? У мня нет такой возможности. Но я могу сказать вам, что обобщенное решение по присоединительному союзу ДА И я беру у того же Розенталя, который доступен всем.  И примеры не придумываю. Я считываю из справочника общий принцип, который  можно понять, приложив какие-то усилия. Я тоже не все понимаю сразу, тоже приходится читать между строк. Потому что это описательный текст с примерами,  там нет или очень мало теории,  и для понимания его смысла надо приложить собственные усилия.

Comment: Хорошо, а какие усилия нужно приложить? Какая нужна техника медитации, дабы познать это? А что вы делали, чтобы понять это?

Comment: Ладно, про технику расскажу чуть позже – я все рано собиралась написать небольшой текст  о том, как я понимаю эту тему у Розенталя.

Comment: Да это просто ядреная халтура со стороны Розенталя, там много подобного рода халтуры.

Comment: Ну ладно, тогда не буду писать. Мы по-разному относимся к Розенталю, для меня он самый главный Учитель. К сожалению, тексты его редактировались,  да и сам он не все сказал, что знал (не успел, не мог или не считал своевременным).  Поэтому его сложно читать  и понимать "напрямую, дословно".  Текст как бы зашифрован, и надо научиться извлекать из него полезную информацию и систематизировать ее.  Но, вероятно, это не ваш метод, если вы так отзываетесь о нем. Спасибо за ваше внимание.

Comment: А почему он зашифрован, а почему я должен её систематизировать, а не автор справочника? Почему никто не допиливает справочник, имеющий столь гигантское количество недостатков? Там можно исправить сотни ошибок в организации тем вообще  и организации внутри каждой темы, можно исправить множество плохих формулировок, можно отчетливо описать какие-то тёмные пятна, можно практики допилить для каждого отдельного сегмента темы, так и для темы в целом. Почему никто не занимается этим? Почему все это остается на таком низком уровне качества?

Comment: Если у нас есть система пунктуации, информацию о которой нужно расшифровывать в каком-то справочнике, как в священном писании, то лингвисты заслуживают смерти.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, оборот "да и вообще возиться с ним" требуется выделить запятыми.
Розенталь пишет:

> Выбор пунктуации может зависеть от конструкции предложения; ср.: *В
> этом предложении, да и в двух соседних, сказуемое выражено краткой
> формой прилагательного* — присоединительный оборот выделяется запятыми;
> *В этом, да и в двух соседних предложениях сказуемое выражено краткой
> формой прилагательного* — нельзя выделить оборот *да и в двух соседних*,
> так как нарушится связь между определением и определяемым словом
> (получится: *в этом… предложениях*).

В вашем случае можно удалить оборот, начинающийся с "да и", и связь не нарушится: *"Но, впрочем, нам тогда глазеть на него... было некогда".*

У Лопатина также имеется пример:

> *Студенты вузов, да и многие школьники, приняли участие в Олимпиаде.*

Comment: Если взять примеры в моем ответе, которые взяты из  Розенталя, то там везде можно удалить таким же образом и связь не нарушится таким же образом.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу присоединений с присоединительным союзом ‟да и” в справочнике Розенталя написана какая-то халтура, как и много о чём еще, но просто напишите по аналогии [с примерами, которые там есть (пункт 2):](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)

> Это называется «экономический кризис», и трудно понять, как вывернутся, да и вывернутся ли предприниматели из этой петли (Газ.).
> Поздно теперь, да и не к чему возвращаться к этому вопросу.
> При проведении подобных сложных экспериментов трудно, да и невозможно избежать отдельных ошибок.
> Канадская нефть приносит прибыль иностранным, главным образом американским монополиям.
> По целым дням, а нередко и ночью велась перестрелка с обеих сторон.